# Should I use notify and wait even when there is only one thread?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class MyLabel extends JLabel {
    int barSize = 0;
    int maxBarSize;

    MyLabel(int maxBarSize) {
        this.maxBarSize = maxBarSize;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        int width = (int) (((double) (this.getWidth())) / maxBarSize * barSize);
        if (width == 0)
            return;
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, this.getHeight());
    }

    synchronized void fill() {
        if (barSize == maxBarSize) {
            try {
                wait(); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
        barSize++;
        repaint();
        notify();
    }

    synchronized void consume() {
        if (barSize == 0) {
            try {
                wait(); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                return;
            }
        }
        barSize--;
        repaint();
        notify();
    }
}

class ConsumerThread extends Thread {
    MyLabel bar;

    ConsumerThread(MyLabel bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                sleep(200);
                bar.consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class TabAndThreadEx extends JFrame {
    MyLabel bar = new MyLabel(100);

    TabAndThreadEx(String title) {
        super(title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(null);
        bar.setBackground(Color.orange);
        bar.setOpaque(true);
        bar.setLocation(20, 50);
        bar.setSize(300, 20);
        c.add(bar);

        c.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                bar.fill();
            }
        });
        setSize(350, 200);
        setVisible(true);

        c.requestFocus();
        ConsumerThread th = new ConsumerThread(bar);
        th.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TabAndThreadEx("press any key");
    }
}
```

It is a Java program that creates a bar and the bar is filled when the key is pressed and the size of the bar is reduced when there is no key input.

What happens if you don't use wait and notify in the fill and consum methods of the MyLabel class?

The thread is only one th of the ConsumerThread, so I don't have to use wait and notify.

Do I need to wait and notify when there is only one thread? If so, why?

Comment: There 2 threads: your `ConsumerThread` and the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) which your key adapter & paint method execute on.

Comment: You wrote in your question: _It is a Java program that creates a bar and the bar is filled when the key is pressed and the size of the bar is reduced when there is no key input_ Copied your code and ran it. It displays an orange bar. It doesn't react at all to pressing keys on the keyboard and if I don't press any keys, nothing changes, no matter how long I wait. Does it work for you?